# Inverse Galois Problem for the special linear group $\rm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am interested in the so-called tame inverse Galois problem which is a refined version of the usual inverse Galois problem, cf. Section 2 in [Birch, Bryan. "Noncongruence subgroups, covers and drawings." The Grothendieck theory of dessins d’enfants (Luminy, 1993) 200 (1994): 25-46.]:

> **(Tame Inverse Galois Problem)**. Given a finite group $G$, is there a tamely ramified Galois extension $N/\mathbb{Q}$ with $\text{Gal}(N/\mathbb{Q})\cong G$?

The paper [SL(2,5) and Frobenius Galois Groups Over Q by Jack Sonn](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/sl25-and-frobenius-galois-groups-over-q/C5132CF9EFEA74BC8908391DD5371E0A) gave a Galois extension $N$ such that $\text{Gal}(N/\mathbb{Q})\cong \rm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$ which is **ramified at $5$** where $\mathbb{F}_5$ is a finite field of order $5$. Under the philosophy of Tame Inverse Galois Problem, my question is the following:

> Is there a Galois extension $N/\mathbb{Q}$ that is **unramified at $5$**
> such that $\text{Gal}(N/\mathbb{Q})\cong \rm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$?

See also the paper [$\widetilde{A}_5$ and $\widetilde{A}_7$ are Galois groups over number fields by WalterFeit](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869386902139) in which an infinity of $\rm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$-extensions are constructed, but I don't know if they meet the requirement, i.e. unramfied at $5$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The [LMFDB](http://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/?galois_group=24t201&ur_primes=5&search_type=List) has examples

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thanks!